# Find out if $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(1-xy)^2}$ is integrable over $[0,1]^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find out if $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(1-xy)^2}$ is integrable over $[0,1]^2$.

If I could use Fubini:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1-xy)^2}dxdy=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-y}dy=\infty $$\

But  can't use Fubini, because this function is non-integrable ( in fact I don't know that yet). How can I approach it without this theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tonnelli's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function) is the version of Fubini's Theorem  where integrability is replaced by non-negativity.

Comment: Your link was not working because of the ' symbol, so I made the theorem's name clickable instead.

Comment: OK, thank you. @Botond

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ be some small number. Consider the L-shaped region
$$M_\epsilon=[1-2\epsilon,1]^2\setminus [1-\epsilon,1]^2.$$
If $(x,y)\in M_\epsilon$, then $xy\in [(1-2\epsilon)^2,1-\epsilon]\subseteq[1-4\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ implying that
$$\frac1{(1-xy)^2}\ge\frac 1{16\epsilon^2}.$$

The region $M_{\epsilon}$ has area $3\epsilon^2$, so it contributes at least $3/16$ to the integral.

But the regions $M_{1/2},M_{1/4},M_{1/8},\ldots$ don't overlap, so together they contribute an unbounded amount to the integral.